# As $\frac1{(1-x)^2} = {1+2x+3x^2 +...nx^{n-1}} + \frac{x^n}{(1-x)^2} + \frac{nx^n}{(1-x)}$, is this is a function of only $x$ or both $x$ and $n$?

Tags: calculus, functional-analysis

$$\frac1{(1-x)^2} = {1+2x+3x^2 +...nx^{n-1}} + \frac{x^n}{(1-x)^2} + \frac{nx^n}{(1-x)}$$

Now, the LHS seems to be a function of only $x$, whereas the RHS seems to be a function of both $x$ as well as $n$. Please remove this ambiguity for me as I don't understand why is it that by simply choosing a value of $x$ on LHS is immaterial of what value $n$ holds.

Comment: I think last term should be  $\frac{nx^n}{(1-x)^2}$ instead of $\frac{nx^n}{(1-x)}$

Comment: Either the $n$'s all cancel out on the right, or it is an equality, not a function.

Comment: Maybe a more immediately understandable example is $x=(x+n)-n$ for every $n$. Yours is just more complex and less intuitively clear

Answer (score 2):

We assume $|x|<1$.

The LHS is a function of $x$ *only*.

The LHS is *equal to* the RHS.

Thus the RHS is a function of $x$ *only*.

Additionally, the term
$$
{1+2x+3x^2 +...nx^{n-1}} \tag1
$$ is a function of $x$ and $n$ and the term
$$
\frac{x^n}{(1-x)^2} + \frac{nx^n}{(1-x)} \tag2
$$ is a function of $x$ and $n$. The sum $(1)+(2)$ is a function of $x$ *only*.

Comment: How? Do the terms on RHS cancel out somehow to yield only x type terms with no n anywhere?

Comment: @user115962 In essence, yes.  I would search for your sum as Olivia labels as $(1)$ above, as it has a famous closed form

Comment: @user115962 $1=(1-x)+x$ the LHS and the RHS don't depend on $x$. Don't confuse $(1-x)$ and $x$ (which both depend on $x$) and the sum $(1-x)+x$ which is equal to $1$ (not depending on $x$ anymore).

Answer (score 2):

This is equality ,not a function
$$\frac1{(1-x)^2} = {1+2x+3x^2 +...nx^{n-1}} + \frac{x^n}{(1-x)^2} + \frac{nx^n}{(1-x)^2}$$
$$\frac1{(1-x)^2} = \frac{d}{dx}\{x+x^2+x^3 +\cdots x^{n}\} + \frac{x^n}{(1-x)^2} + \frac{nx^n}{(1-x)^2}$$
$$x+x^2+x^3 +\cdots x^{n}=\frac{x(1-x^n)}{1-x}$$
$$\frac1{(1-x)^2} = \frac{d}{dx}\left\{\frac{x(1-x^n)}{1-x}\right\} + \frac{x^n}{(1-x)^2} + \frac{nx^n}{(1-x)^2}$$
$$\frac1{(1-x)^2}=\frac1{(1-x)^2}$$
This hold true for $$\forall \space  x \in \mathbb{R} -\{1\} $$

Comment: $0$ Should be in the domain, but $1$ not.

Comment: @NigelOvermars Thanks,fixed it .

Answer (score 0):

If you rewrite as:

$$\lim\limits_{n\to\infty}\sum\limits_{i=1}^n ix^{i-1}$$

the '$n$' is just an index.